# Number of Mercurial repositories per project on Google Code

Tags: mercurial, google-code

I'm not sure whether it belongs to Stack Overflow, however it's definitely programming-related. I have the following question: what is the limit on the number of user repositories per project that are available for addition on `Administer` tab (apart from `default` and `wiki` repositories)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just discovered the following [link](http://groups.google.com/group/google-code-hosting/browse_thread/thread/129cfdcf964ac85a/9685a101786a41f2) saying that there is a limit of 10 Mercurial repositories per project.